# Maven : Automatically incremental the version in maven

Tags: maven-2

I am using Maven 2.0 
As you can see from the below line , i am hardcoding the version as 1.0

Is it possible that for every build the version automatically increments .

```
  <copy file="D:/MyWeb/service/target/MyWeb-ws-1.0.war" tofile="C:/Softwares/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/webapps/MyWeb-ws-1.0.war" />
```

Please suggest , thank you very much .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at using the [Build Number Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) for this.

As documented in their web page,

> This plugin works in one of 3 ways: with an SCM, with a sequential
>   build number, or with a timestamp.

You can choose the one which is convenient to you.